# Annoying SNAPSHOT releases in Grails list-plugin-updates command

Tags: grails, plugins, updates

Is there a way to tell the Grails `list-plugin-updates` command to ignore SNAPSHOT releases?

```
bash-3.2$ grails list-plugin-updates
Plugins with available updates are listed below:
-------------------------------------------------------------
<Plugin>            <Current>         <Available>
resources           1.2.8             1.2.9-SNAPSHOT
remote-pagination   0.4.6             0.4.7
platform-core       1.0.0             1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
mongodb             2.0.1             3.0.1
mail                1.0.5             1.0.6-SNAPSHOT
joda-time           1.4               1.5-SNAPSHOT
hibernate           3.6.10.15         3.6.10.16-SNAPSHOT
```

There have been many times when a "real" update has been obscured by a SNAPSHOT release, so I still have to check the Grails website to see the current versions.  We are building a production system and almost never want to include a SNAPSHOT release of any plugin.

Documentation:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/list-plugin-updates.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently no but it seems like it should be ignoring snapshots so feel free to raise a JIRA issue (and even contribute a fix!)